# How can I see what's in my HttpContext.Cache

Tags: asp.net, caching, httpcontext.cache

Are there any good tools to see how much data (or even better the values of that data) is in my `HttpContext.Cache`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Isis](http://isis.codeplex.com/documentation) is a control panel for ASP.NET applications that allows easy visibility into the application's assemblies (debug or not), logging, errors, **cache**, session, performance counters, and more.
( You have to compile it from source. )

[CacheManager](http://aspalliance.com/cachemanager/default.aspx) although quite old - it just works.

Edit: Based on CacheManager i wrote my own implementation, where i use Jayrock.Json to visualize data values of complex types / lists as a **readable** json.

Answer (score 2):

Update; The previous link to Scott Cate's article is gone now. Since there was quite a bit of code there (which is not easy to summarize here without reproducing the entire blog), I'm updating this answer with an easier choice: [Aspy](http://bytecarrot.com/aspy/)

> Aspy is totally free ASP.NET Session and Cache online viewer. It can be integrated with any ASP.NET web application including ASP.NET MVC and Web API. It is ready to use right after the installation. More detailed description is available on our website:

Available on NuGet and needs no coding at all.

```
PM> Install-Package Aspy
```

Short [Screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKjiauAy59k)

Comment: @DotNetDreamer: See my updates. This is why link only answers are not a good fit but as I mentioned, there was really no easy way for me to summarize the blog's gist here.